# Contact form PHPMailer sending button is stuck loading

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmailer, contact-form

I'm having trouble with my contact form. I'm using the code from [jon bake](https://github.com/jonmbake/bootstrap3-contact-form). However I can't get it to work, it's not sending the mail (or I'm not receiving it) and I don't even get the "success" message after pressing 'send'. [This is how it looks in the 'console'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6nnx.jpg).
I also get

HTTP500 : Server Error - Failed to execute request because the server encountered an unexpected condition .
( XHR ) : POST - 
from console.

HTML

```
    <form role="form" id="feedbackForm" method = "post" data-toggle="validator" data-disable="false">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="name">Name *</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required/>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked form-control-feedback"></i></span>
          </div>
          <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter your name.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="phone">Phone</label>
          <input type="tel" class="form-control optional" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone (Optional)"/>
          <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid phone number.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

          <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid e-mail address.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="email">Email Address *</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required/>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked form-control-feedback"></i></span>
          </div>
          <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid e-mail address.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="message">Message *</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <textarea rows="5" cols="30" class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked form-control-feedback"></i></span>
          </div>
          <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a message.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfIxCQTAAAAAK7ZBb9liJNpaebx12UbmOfiqtl9"></div>
          <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please check that you are not a robot.</span>
        </div>
        <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a the security code.</span>
        <button type="submit" id="feedbackSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-loading-text="Sending..." style="display: block; margin-top: 10px;">Send Feedback</button>
      </form>
    </div><!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->
  <hr>
</div><!--/.container-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vender/intl-tel-input/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/contact-form.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

The contact-form.js

```
(function () {
  //using regular expressions, validate email
  var contactFormUtils = {
    isValidEmail: function (email) {
      var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]      {2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
},
//if no form errors, remove or hide error messages
clearErrors: function () {
  $('#emailAlert').remove();
  $('#feedbackForm .help-block').hide();
  $('#feedbackForm .form-group').removeClass('has-error');
},
//upon form clear remove the checked class and replace with unchecked class. Also reset Google ReCaptcha
clearForm: function () {
  $('#feedbackForm .glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked').css({color: ''});
  $('#feedbackForm input,textarea').val("");
  grecaptcha.reset();
},
//when error, show error messages and track that error exists
addError: function ($input) {
  var parentFormGroup = $input.parents('.form-group');
  parentFormGroup.children('.help-block').show();
  parentFormGroup.addClass('has-error');
},
addAjaxMessage: function(msg, isError) {
  $("#feedbackSubmit").after('<div id="emailAlert" class="alert alert-' + (isError ? 'danger' : 'success') + '" style="margin-top: 5px;">' + $('<div/>').text(msg).html() + '</div>');
    }
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#phone").intlTelInput) {
      $("#phone").intlTelInput({validationScript: "assets/vender/intl-tel-    input/js/isValidNumber.js"});
      $(".intl-tel-input.inside").css('width', '100%');
    }

$("#feedbackSubmit").click(function() {
  var $btn = $(this);
  $btn.button('loading');
  contactFormUtils.clearErrors();

  //do a little client-side validation -- check that each field has a value and e-mail field is in proper format
  //use bootstrap validator (https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator) if provided, otherwise a bit of custom validation
  var $form = $("#feedbackForm"),
    hasErrors = false;
  if ($form.validator) {
    hasErrors =  $form.validator('validate').hasErrors;
  } else {
    $('#feedbackForm input,#feedbackForm textarea').not('.optional').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      if (($this.is(':checkbox') && !$this.is(':checked')) || !$this.val()) {
        hasErrors = true;
        contactFormUtils.addError($(this));
      }
    });
    var $email = $('#email');
    if (!contactFormUtils.isValidEmail($email.val())) {
      hasErrors = true;
      contactFormUtils.addError($email);
    }
    var $phone = $('#phone');
    if ($phone.val() && $phone.intlTelInput && !$phone.intlTelInput("isValidNumber")) {
      hasErrors = true;
      contactFormUtils.addError($phone.parent());
    }
  }
  //if there are any errors return without sending e-mail
  if (hasErrors) {
    $btn.button('reset');
    return false;
  }
 //send the feedback e-mail
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "../../library/sendmail.php",
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      contactFormUtils.addAjaxMessage(data.message, false);
      contactFormUtils.clearForm();
    },
    error: function(response) {
      contactFormUtils.addAjaxMessage(response.responseJSON.message, true);
    },
    complete: function() {
      $btn.button('reset');
    }
 });
  return false;

});
$('#feedbackForm input, #feedbackForm textarea').change(function () {
  var checkBox = $(this).siblings('span.input-group-addon').children('.glyphicon');
  if ($(this).val()) {
    checkBox.removeClass('glyphicon-unchecked').addClass('glyphicon-check').css({color: 'green'});
  } else {
    checkBox.removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked').css({color: ''});
  }
});
  });
})();
```

And the PHP

```
  /**
   * Sets error header and json error message response.
   *
   * @param  String $messsage error message of response
   * @return void
      */
  function errorResponse ($messsage) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    die(json_encode(array('message' => $messsage)));
  }
  /**
   * Pulls posted values for all fields in $fields_req array.
   * If a required field does not have a value, an error response is given.
   */
  function constructMessageBody () {
    $fields_req =  array("name" => true, "email" => true, "message" => true);
    $message_body = "";
    foreach ($fields_req as $name => $required) {
      $postedValue = $_POST[$name];
      if ($required && empty($postedValue)) {
        errorResponse("$name is empty.");
      } else {
        $message_body .= ucfirst($name) . ":  " . $postedValue . "\n";
      }
    }
    return $message_body;
  }
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  //do Captcha check, make sure the submitter is not a robot:)...
  $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
  $opts = array('http' =>
    array(
      'method'  => 'POST',
      'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'content' => http_build_query(array('secret'     => '6LfIxCQTAAAAABhWEJuLVdzE9m_-cwbBs9lM1xVi', 'response' => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]))
    )
  );
  $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
  $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, false, $context, -1, 40000));

  if (!$result->success) {
    errorResponse('reCAPTCHA checked failed!');
  }

  //attempt to send email
  $messageBody = constructMessageBody();
  require_once './vender/php_mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  include_once './vender/php_mailer/class.phpmailer.php';
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 2
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->Port = 587;
  $mail->Username = "gmail.com";
  $mail->Password = "password";

  $mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
  $mail->addAddress "gmail.com";
  $mail->Subject = "Contact Form";
  $mail->Body  = $message_body;


  //try to send the message
  if($mail->send()) {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Your message was successfully     submitted.'));
  } else {
    errorResponse('An expected error occured while attempting to send the     email: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
  } 
?>
```

I'm very new to JavaScript and PHP so maybe I've missed something but I've tried to find a solution on Google but not been able to find one.

I hope I've made myself clear, thanks.

Comment: Having SMTPDebug = 2 set will break your JSON response as PHPMailer debug output is not in JSON format. As usual though, an error 500 means you have an error in your PHP script, so check your server logs to see what it is. Test one thing at a time - get your PHP working separately from your javascript, otherwise you can't tell which is causing the problem. This is basic debugging. Base your code on the provided examples and do what the docs say, don't just blindly copy and paste things you find.